# Create a KMS custom Key in CloudFormation template for different region

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

Is there any way to generate a custom KMS Key via CloudFormation template in a different region than the region which is specified in the respective AWS User account you use to run the template?

Merci A

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

No, not directly.

**Long answer:**

It can actually be done in one of two ways. First, using [StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-concepts.html), you can create a single template that will be deployed in selected accounts (1 in this occurence) and regions.

The second way to achieve your goal is to use a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to create your KMS keys in other regions. This custom resource will invoke a Lambda function to handle the lifecycle of your KMS keys. Within this Lambda you will have to call the appropriate APIs to create/update/delete the KMS keys in the desired region.

Comment: Merci, was afraid it would be like that. However I'm having difficulties to generate a kms key in a different region with my admin account at all. How is that doable via AWSCLI? there is no --region option.